# How to convert Array<T?>? into Array<T> in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm taking my first steps in Kotlin, and trying to write a simple string split function. I started with this:

```
fun splitCSV(s : String) : Array<String> {
    return s.split(",");
}
```

Which I guess can be also written like this:

```
fun splitCSV(s : String) : Array<String> = s.split(",");
```

But I'm getting a type error, since s.split returns an `Array<String?>?` and not `Array<String>`. I couldn't find a simple way to do a cast, so I wrote this function to do the conversion:

```
fun forceNotNull<T>(a : Array<T?>?) : Array<T> {
    return Array<T>(a!!.size, { i -> a!![i]!! });
}

fun splitCSV(s : String) : Array<String> = forceNotNull(s.split(","));
```

However, now I'm getting a runtime error:

> ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String

If I change T in `forceNotNull` to String, then it works, so I guess I'm close to a solution.

Is this the right way to go about it? And if it is, how can I fix `forceNotNull` to work in the generic case?

Comment: Function `sureItemsNotNull` already added: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1391

Comment: @StasKurilin can you give an example of how that could be used with the above function definition?

Comment: The exception you are getting is a bug, of course. The easiest solution in this case is just a cast:

s.split(",") as Array<String>

Comment: @Andery I guess the warning "This cast can never succeed" is also a bug. Nice to hear from the authority, thanks!

Comment: This should be closed as a duplicate of 33583235.  The other question is newer, more direct and answers are for current kotlin 1.0 betas and beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the best method, but this seems to work:

```
fun splitCSV(s : String) : Array<String> {
  return ( s.split(",") as? Array<String>? ).sure() ;
}
```

Although IntelliJ highlights the `as?` with *"This cast can never succeed"*...  So my initial optimism is fading

Oddly though, it seems to work...

As does:

```
fun splitCSV(s : String) : Array<String> {
  return s.split(",").sure() as Array<String> ;
}
```

But with the same warning...  I'm getting confused, so I'll stop now :-/

#### Edit

Of course, you can get it to work with `List<String>`:

```
import java.util.List

fun splitCSV(s : String) : List<String> {
  return s.split(",")!!.map<String?,String> { it!! }
}
```

but that wasn't the question ;-)

Comment: Like Andrey said, the cast is the right approach, so you were very close... Accepting this.

Comment: Can you update the code here for `.sure()` to `!!` since that is outdated code.

Answer (score 1):

Since the time of this post, kotlin has changed a lot and now there are lot easier and nice(*explicit casts should be avoided*) ways of converting `Array<T?>?` to `Array<T>`, one way would be to do

```
val data: Array<String?>? = getData()
val notNullArray: Array<String> = data?.filterNotNull()?.toTypedArray() ?: arrayOf()
```

here we make use of [`filterNotNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-not-null.html) to get a `List<String>` and then convert that list to an `Array<String>`, if however the original array is `null` then we simply use `arrayOf()`, which given us an empty `Array<T>`

`?:` is the [`elvis`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) operator which returns the expression on its left if its not null otherwise it returns the value of expression on the right

Answer (score 0):

in Simple way you can cast string to Array in kotlin by:-

```
fun splitCSV(s: String) = s.split(",").toTypedArray()
```

call this function by

```
val array: Array<String> = splitCSV("ABC,XYZ,test,rupesh")
```

in kotlin CharSequence.split(regex) return  List so if you want to change in type Array use .toTypedArray() method